# sed/awk hide/mask field in a json file

Tags: json, bash, awk, sed, hide

I am trying to mask/hide a value of a field in a json file.

I have json that looks something like this:

```
    "PLUSDATA": {
        "global": {
            "auth_type": "login", 
            "passkey": "SENSETIVE_CONTENT_TO_BE_HIDDEN", 
            "src_intf": "Loopback0", 
            "timeout": "5"
        }
    },
```

I'd like to parse my json and have the "**SENSETIVE_CONTENT_TO_BE_HIDDEN**" masked with * ( length does not matter

```
    "PLUSDATA": {
        "global": {
            "auth_type": "login", 
            "passkey": "****", 
            "src_intf": "Loopback0", 
            "timeout": "5"
        }
    },
```

Thank you,

I am trying some variations of awk/sed but just can't get the desired result.

Comment: Edit your question to show what you think was your best attempt to solve this. We can't help you fix code we can't see. Can you install the `jq` utility. It is designed for editing `json`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get part of sed working when given a concrete line:

```
echo '{"passkey":"sensetive_cotnent"}' | sed 's/\({"passkey":"\)[^"]*\("}\)/\1xxxxxxxxxxx\2/g'
```

which parses it correctly.

But i can't seem to get the same result when doing something like:

```
cat my_sensetive_file.json | sed 's/\({"passkey":"\)[^"]*\("}\)/\1xxxxxxxxxxx\2/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ jq -r '.PLUSDATA.global.passkey = "******"' file.json
{
  "PLUSDATA": {
    "global": {
      "auth_type": "login",
      "passkey": "******",
      "src_intf": "Loopback0",
      "timeout": "5"
    }
  }
}
```